# Issues with binding

Tags: python, tkinter

I bound some keys to my save_file function, it does save as first then gives an error code "AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'get'". I don't really understand cos when I click on the button that calls in the main menu, it works. Any idea what I should do?

```
    self.text = Text(root, bg="white",  wrap='word', undo=True, foreground="black", exportselection="no")
    self.text.bind("<Control-Alt-s>", self.save_file_as)
    self.text.bind("<Control-s>", self.save_file)
    self.text.bind("<Control-o>", self.open_file)
    self.text.focus_set()
    self.text.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
```

The functions 
 self.filename = ''
        self._filetypes = [('Text', '*.txt'), ('All files', '*'), ]

```
    #calls the save function
def saveFile(self):
    self.save_file(self.text)

#saving all The files
    def save_file(self, texts):
        self.text2 = texts
        if (self.filename == ''):
            self.save_file_as()
        else:
            f = open(self.filename, 'w')
            f.write(self.text2.get('1.0', 'end'))  # change every 'self' that refers to the Text, to self.text2
            f.close()
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('FYI', 'File Saved.')
        root.title(self.filename)
    def save_file_as(self, whatever=None):
        self.filename = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt', filetypes=self._filetypes)
        f = open(self.filename, 'w')
        f.write(self.text2.get('1.0', 'end'))
        f.close()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('FYI', 'File Saved')
```

Comment: The code you provided is not enough to guess the origin of your problem

Answer (score 1):

When a bound function is called, it passes an event object into it. What you think is your parameter `text` is in fact that event. Try this:

```
    def save_file(self, event):
        self.text2 = event.widget
        if (self.filename == ''):
            self.save_file_as()
        else:
            f = open(self.filename, 'w')
            f.write(self.text2.get('1.0', 'end'))  # change every 'self' that refers to the Text, to self.text2
            f.close()
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('FYI', 'File Saved.')
        root.title(self.filename)

    def save_file_as(self, event=None, whatever=None):
        self.filename = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt', filetypes=self._filetypes)
        f = open(self.filename, 'w')
        f.write(self.text2.get('1.0', 'end'))
        f.close()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('FYI', 'File Saved')
```